# get_posts is duplicating

Tags: theme-development

I have the following code where I want to show one query with the last "post type" post and one query where I want to show the rest. Problem is that the last query is duplicating the first one. How may I fix this issue?

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 1,
        'offset'           => 1,
        'category'         => '',
        'category_name'    => '',
        'orderby'          => 'date',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'include'          => '',
        'exclude'          => '',
        'meta_key'         => '',
        'meta_value'       => '',
        'post_type'        => 'prosjekter',
        'post_mime_type'   => '',
        'post_parent'      => '',
        'author'       => '',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true 
    );
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($posts_array as $row) {

    ?>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
      </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <?php $args2 = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 5,
        'offset'           => 2,
        'tag' => '',
        'category'         => '',
        'category_name'    => '',
        'orderby'          => 'date',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'include'          => '',
        'exclude'          => '',
        'meta_key'         => '',
        'meta_value'       => '',
        'post_type'        => 'prosjekter',
        'post_mime_type'   => '',
        'post_parent'      => '',
        'author'       => '',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true 
    );
    $posts_array2 = get_posts( $args2 );
    foreach ($posts_array2 as $row2) {

    ?>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
      </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save the IDs of the posts from first loop you want to exclude in second loop into an array, and the use that array to exclude the posts. Also, always reset post data after query.

Here's your code with the modification.

```
<div class="row">
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'offset'           => 1,
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'prosjekter',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($posts_array as $row) {

    $exclude[] = get_the_ID(); // Save The Post ID in an array

?>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
  </div>
<?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
<div class="row">
<?php $args2 = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 2,
    'tag' => '',
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'prosjekter',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'post__not_in'     => $exclude //Exclude the IDs
);
$posts_array2 = get_posts( $args2 );
foreach ($posts_array2 as $row2) {

?>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
  </div>
<?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

**EDIT:** Since you are excluding only the latest post, you can try the `offset` parameter in second loop too.